# Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/

Tags: gentoo, gitlab, rubygems

I have gentoo linux where I run a gitlab instance. I'm stuck upgrading to **dev-vcs/gitlab-gitaly-1.7.1** When the installation executes command

```
bundle install --deployment
```

The output is:

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
make[1]: *** [Makefile:32: ../.ruby-bundle] Error 17
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-vcs/gitlab-gitaly-1.7.1/work/gitlab-gitaly-1.7.1/_build'
make: *** [Makefile:24: build] Error 2
 * ERROR: dev-vcs/gitlab-gitaly-1.7.1::gitlab failed (compile phase):
 *   emake failed
 *
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-vcs/gitlab-gitaly-1.7.1::gitlab'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-vcs/gitlab-gitaly-1.7.1::gitlab'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-vcs/gitlab-gitaly-1.7.1/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-vcs/gitlab-gitaly-1.7.1/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-vcs/gitlab-gitaly-1.7.1/work/gitlab-gitaly-1.7.1'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-vcs/gitlab-gitaly-1.7.1/work/gitlab-gitaly-1.7.1'
```

I have tried to reinstalling bundler, upgraded ruby, disabled ipv6 routing, but nothing helped. I have verified that I'm able to access the https://rubygems.org/ using wget and I'm able to ping rubygems.org.
I guess that there may be problem with openssl. I have dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2r and dev-lang/ruby-2.4.6 and dev-lang/ruby-2.5.5, but using either of those doesn't work.
Does anyone encountered and solved this problem?

Comment: Can you please put the "complete build log" on pastebin or similar? With these things the answer is rarely in the returned message. Edit: Just saw how old this was.